# Create record in on table after creating record in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is how my ERD looks like

[image]

I have users, that have autoincremented ID. When new user is added, there is trigger which inserts into biodata (in biodata table will be later info about user DOB, city etc.) new record. Biodata user_id is also autoincremented and I am using following trigger to fill it whenever new user is added:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger trigger_biodata
after insert 
on user for each row
BEGIN
    insert into biodata values(null);
END $$
delimiter ;
```

But there is an error when user insert fails saying:

> insert into user values(null,'biesiek','to','faja')   Error Code: 1452.
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`mydb`.`biodata`, CONSTRAINT `fk_biodata_user2` FOREIGN KEY
> (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))

So I am looking for info how to fix that or how to make possible to make second table getting same user_id whenever new user is added.

Comment: Could you also provide the index definitions? That would help a lot :)

Comment: You can’t (effectively) have biodata.user_id be both autoincremented and be a foreign key into user (nor would you want to).  Take off the autoincrement, and insert the user_id in your trigger from user.id.

Comment: @RBarryYoung how should that trigger look exactly like?

Comment: Same as you have, except the INSERT line should be `INSERT into bioinformation(user_id) values (LAST_INSERT_ID());`

Comment: @RBarryYoung doesnt work in case when I insert null instead off id into user table. Any idea on how to fix that? I need this because when new users on site will be creating new accounts they will pass only login, password and email, not id.

Comment: Just use Akina's version, that works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_biodata
AFTER INSERT 
ON user 
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO biodata (user_id) VALUES (NEW.id);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c265d6f2703052e5b1a806c6d270936e

Comment: Pretty sure that `NEW.id` should be `LAST_INSERT_ID` here.  You don't want a New ID, you want to copy the `user.id` that was just created.  Also, the OP still would need to take the autoincrement off the `bioinformation.user_id` column.

Comment: @RBarryYoung exactly. After making for example
insert into user values(null,'examplelogin','examplepassword','examplemail')
which will make this record have id=3 (after autoincrement)
i would like my user_id in new record to be id=3

Comment: Well `NEW.id` sure looks like Oracle PSQL, not MySql.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Fiddle added, ensure.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Reference: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Oh, I see, `NEW` is the insert trigger's pseudo-table/row alias for new rows.